# why the code is not running after 'next i'

Tags: vba

```
Sub seivedata()
Dim Dsheet As Worksheet: Set Dsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Equipment Logon & Logoff Report")
Dim Osheet As Worksheet: Set Osheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")
Dim onoff As Boolean
Dim arr As Variant

Call turnoffsettings(onoff = True)

    MsgBox "starting transfer"

    arr = Dsheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

        Dim i As Long, j As Long, row As Long
        row = 2
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If i + 1 = UBound(arr, 1) Then End
            If arr(i, 1) = arr(i + 1, 1) And arr(i, 2) = "LOGOFF" Then
                For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                    Osheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = arr(i, 1)
                    Osheet.Cells(row, 2).Value = DateValue(Format(arr(i, 3), "dd/mm/yyyy")) + TimeValue(Format(arr(i, 3), "hh:mm"))
                    Osheet.Cells(row, 3).Value = DateValue(Format(arr(i + 1, 3), "dd/mm/yyyy")) + TimeValue(Format(arr(i + 1, 3), "hh:mm"))
                    Osheet.Cells(row, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(Osheet.Cells(row, 3).Value - Osheet.Cells(row, 2).Value, "hh:mm")
                Next j
            row = row + 1
            End If
        Next i
        Set arr = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "completed transfer"

    'Dim lrow As Long
    'lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row
    'Debug.Print lrow

    'Osheet.Range("F2:F" & lrow).Value = Osheet.Range("A2:A" & lrow).Value
    'Osheet.Range("F2:F" & lrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
    
Call turnoffsettings(onoff = False)
End Sub
```

Comment: When your code reaches the statement `If i + 1 = UBound(arr, 1) Then End`  and the condition is True, it will execute the `End` - statement, and that stops the execution of any code.

Comment: That was it! I was completely blind to that line. I needed it as I wanted the code to stop after it reaches the end of the array.

Comment: Executing the code step by step with the debugger [F8] will reveal such behaviour.